# When is the next point release to be available?

Tags: 12.04, updates, lightdm, release-management

There are several things I love about 12.04 LTS, but several bugs which make it terrible, like the LightDM issues with the XServer and whatnot. I'm really hoping on the next point release to fix these annoying problems, but I want to know... when is it expected to be released to the public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 12.04.1 point release will be released August 23. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseSchedule

However, most fixes are made in new versions and those that are released to stable are generally rolled out gradually. If you have specific backport requests, or other unresolved issues, you should file a bug about it on Launchpad. see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReportingBugs

Is this display manager issue you describe a flickering when logging in? And if so, are you using the radeon AMD/ATI driver? (`lsmod | grep radeon`)

Answer (score 3):

According to the official Ubuntu wiki it will be released August 23rd 2012.

[Precise release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule?action=show&redirect=PreciseReleaseSchedule)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu releases bug fix upgrades all the time to various packages, which you can get if you follow the `-updates` repository for your distribution.

When there is a point release update to the CD/DVD images (which only happens for Ubuntu LTS), it simply incorporates all of the updates made thus far, which you would have installed already had you been installing updates on an existing installation.  So if you already install all available updates, you won't get anything *new* if you re-install from one of the point release updates.

That said, point release updates of Ubuntu LTS usually come out roughly every January and August at the moment.